# Apagar linhas em múltiplas tabelas

Tags: java, sql

Estou a tentar apagar informação de 2 tabelas em simultâneo que estão ligadas uma com a outra mas  não estou a conseguir, dá-me este erro:
Alguém me ajuda por favor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu erro fala de erro de violação de constraints, você pode desabilitar as mesmas antes de apagar os registros.

Comment: -1 Pelo código e informação que estão anexadas em imagens.

Comment: Como assim? Podiam ser mais explícitos por favor?

Comment: Miguel, seja bem vindo. O ideal é que você informe o erro e o código na própria pergunta fazendo uso de formatação. Assim evitaria o uso da imagem. Veja mais aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Qual o banco de dados? você quer deletar todos os dados dessa tabela que tenha relação com a outro? ou deleta os dados das duas tabelas que tem a mesma relação?

Answer (score 1):

Como você não especificou o banco de dados, estou respondendo em SQL SERVER, e tabelas do meu banco de dados;

Você pode aproveitar o "o id excluído" da tabela algo como:

```
begin transaction;

   declare @deletedIds table ( id int );

   delete e
   output p.IdPessoa into @deletedIds
   from Pessoas p
    join Estados e
    on e.IdPessoa = p.IdPessoa

   delete P
   from Pessoas P
    join @deletedIds d
      on d.id = P.IdPessoa;

commit transaction;
```

Você pode pegar o id da tabela com o "output" observe que a tabela que é a primeira a ser deletada é a que tem relação de dependência nesse caso (Estados).

Comment: É em Java SQL, será que consegue me ajudar em JavaSQL? obrigado pela ajuda @MarconcílioSouza

Comment: Java sql. Tem um banco de dados desses não sabia